# С помощью чего лучше сделать разрезание картинки?

Tags: алгоритм, библиотеки, поиск-библиотек

Мне надо разрезать одну картинку на несколько картинок, и сохранить (придется работать с дугами и кругами).
Хочется узнать какой ЯП лучше использовать, и какую библиотеку (учитывая то, что придется работать с дугами).

Answer (score 2):

Что лучше использовать не подскажу, т.к. вариантов и библиотек куча.

Как один из вариантов быстрых и не сложных  - Python, opencv:
[Тут](https://coderoad.ru/36911877/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-opencv-python) пример как вырезать окружность.

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня есть еще вопрос: а можно вырезать с помощью этой библиотеки форму состоящую из дуг(ну что - то в форме глаза например)?

Comment: @OneOrigiN в теории - да, но как это делать на практике, не подскажу.